# How can I filter email messages in Alpine v2.03 email client?

Tags: spam-prevention, email-filter, alpine-mail

In my school, our web admin gave us a text-based email client to manage our inbox. This client is called *Alpine*. Its productive version is `2.03`.

We have a lot of spam in our inbox, but I cannot ask to admin for improving spam filters. So I want to find a way to filter incoming messages. I have found that spam comes from a set of domains. I have those domains logged into a text file.

For example, `my-spam-domains.txt` looks like:

```
domain1.com
domain2.org
domain3.co
domain4.mx
```

Is there a way to filter spam using this list of domains?
Maybe with some `*rc` file?

Comment: Do you have access to _procmail_ or similar?

Answer (score 0):

In alpine press m s r f a, then in the "From pattern" insert your spam domains, in Filter action Move the message to your spam folder or Delete it.